# Database choice for Multiple Questions and Answer

Tags: mysql, database, entity, entity-relationship

I'm about to develop a database used for storing questionnaire with a indefinite number of questions. This database will communicate with a server, used for registering the answers and retrieving them when needed. For each user, I need to store the answer to each question, which is *server-side* mandatory.

The structure should be like that:

```
QUESTIONNAIRE:
Questionnaire n.1 (Question1,Question2,...,QuestionN)
Questionnaire n.2 (Question1,...,QuestionM)
...

USER:
User1
User2
...

ANSWERS
User1 - Questionnaire n.1 (AnswToQuestion1, AnswToQuestion2...AnswToQuestionN)
User2 - Questionnaire n.1 (AnswToQuestion1, AnswToQuestion2...AnswToQuestionN)
User2 - Questionnaire n.2 (AnswToQuestion1, AnswToQuestion2...AnswToQuestionM)
```

Given the specifications above, I face 2 major problems:

1. Indefinite number of questions means that a table must store each individual questions for each questionnaire
2. There should be a corrispondence between question and answer

I thought about 2 different solution for facing such problems, but I can really decide between the 2.

The first one would consist in creating 5 differents table, as follows:
[image: ER]

The idea is basically to store users in `USER` table, and for each user store an `ANSWER` which refers to a specific questionnaire. This gives an information like 'user x has replied to questionnaire'. Then, the unique id `id:ANSWER` would be used to mark a given answer in `MARKETINGANSWER`. The `QUESTIONNAIRE` table would save each instance of a questionnaire, and provide an unique id to link each different question in the `MARKETINGQUESTION` table. At the end, the unique id `id:MARKETINGQUESTION` would be used to map a question to a given answer.

What does not convince me: this has too many layers of indirection. I do not like the forced connection of `MARKETINGANSWER` and `MARKETINGQUESTION`, yet I need a way to map them. Moreover, I need the general table for `ANSWER`, since it provides some general info about the questionnaire (the hidden columns).

Then I thougth about a second approach: creating an unique `ANSWER` and `QUESTIONNAIRE` table which would envelop in a `TEXT` attribute the series of answers/questions separated by a special escape character (such as `#&`, for instance). This would ruin the mapping, but it can be implemented in the web application - I was thinking about a control on the number of question/answer, the ordering would be ensured on questionnaire registration and commit on the database. Moreover, the schema would be cleaner. Yet, I would lose a consistent representation in the database schema.

I would like, if possible, some suggestion about the proposed solutions. I am pretty sure there is something simple I cannot quite grasp.
Thank you in advance.